# Holder continuity of an infinite series o functions

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis

For $\lambda \in (0,1]$ define
$$f_\lambda (x) = \sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{ \cos(2^n x)}{2^{n \lambda} }$$ for $x \in [0,\pi]$.  How can I prove that  $f_\lambda$  is  $\alpha$ Holder continuous on $[0, \pi]$ for all  $0 < \alpha < \lambda$.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Study the cases $2^{-(k+1)}\le |x-y|\le 2^{-k}$ for $k\ge 1.$

Comment: Could you please elaborate on that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume $$2^{-k-1}\le |x-y|\le 2^{-k}$$ Then $$|\cos(2^nx)-\cos(2^ny)|\le 2^{n}|x-y|\le 2^{n-k}$$ Hence $$|f(x)-f(y)|\le \sum_{n=1}^k2^{n-k-\lambda n}+2\sum_{n=k+1}^\infty 2^{-\lambda n} $$ Let $0<\lambda <1.$ Then $$|f(x)-f(y)|\le {2^{-k}2^{(1-\lambda)(k+1)}\over 2^{1-\lambda}-1}+2\cdot {2^{-\lambda(k+1)}\over 1-2^{-\lambda}}\\ ={2\over 2^{1-\lambda}-1}2^{-\lambda(k+1)}+{2\over 1-2^{-\lambda}}2^{-\lambda(k+1)}\\ \le c_\lambda|x-y|^\lambda$$
For $0<\alpha<\lambda =1$ the same reasoning gives $$|f(x)-f(y)|\le k2^{-k}+2^{-k}=(k+1)2^{-k}\\ ={(k+1)2^\alpha\over 2^{(1-\alpha)k}}2^{-\alpha (k+1)}\le c|x-y|^\alpha$$ as the first ratio tends to $0,$ hence is bounded by a constant $c.$